# Testing a constructor instantiates another class

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have some code that looks like so:

```
var testLib = function(params) {
    this.conf = new testLib.Config(params);
};

testLib.Config = function(params) {
    //do stuff with params
};
```

Instantiated like so:

```
var ins = new testLib({});
```

I want to test that the tesLib constructor correctly instantiates the Config with the correct arguments using jasmine. I'm trying this:

```
    spyOn(window,'testLib.Config');
    var test = new testLib('testparam');
    expect(testLib.Config).toHaveBeenCalledWith('testparam');
```

But this doesn't work. I get an error saying testLib.Config method does not exist. It definitely does exist as I'm including my entire library so it's available to jasmine.

how can I test this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of the `spyOn` method should be the property name that references the `function/method`.

Try `spyOn(testLib, 'Config')`. It should work.

Also, javascript is case senstive. property `Config` is uppercase C. Check the second parameter of your `spyOn` method.